# Can a star reflect light from another star? (Enough for it to be visible)

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, stars

Suppose a binary star system has relatively a dim red star (such as a red giant or red dwarf) and a very bright blue star. From standing on a planet much closer to the red star, would it be possible to look up into the sky and see something like this:

[image]

where the lighter-coloured part is reflected light from the blue star.

There are really two questions here: (1) would the red star reflect light from the blue one at all, given that its surface is made of slightly ionised hydrogen gas (in contrast to planets like Jupiter, which are mostly not ionised); and (2) would the amount of light reflected be enough not to be overwhelmed by the light from the red star?

I'm also interested in whether the colour difference between the emitted red light and reflected bluish light would be enough to be detected by the human eye. (We can assume the human is wearing very dark glasses.)

A bonus question: if star-reflected starlight of this kind does exist, are there cases where it can be detected from Earth, spectroscopically?

Comment: @probably_someone hmm, that's kind of a good point. My reasoning was that a star is mostly made of hydrogen and thus should reflect similarly to  Jupiter, but as you point out that reasoning is flawed - I will amend the question.

Comment: You're correct that stars are mostly made of hydrogen. The issue is that the hydrogen in stars is ionized, which gives a material with completely different optical properties.

Comment: @probably_someone yes, I realised that as soon as I read your comment.

Comment: @probably_someone though I'm not sure to what extent the *surface* of the Sun is ionised, and the answer [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/7883/what-is-the-degree-of-ionization-is-the-solar-photosphere) suggests maybe not very much. It's probably much less for a red star, too, since the surface is less hot. I've no idea to what degree the a small amount of ionisation affects reflectivity, so my question seems unexpectedly more interesting than I thought it was :)

Comment: Hint: good blackbody emitters are also good absorbers.

Comment: @ThePhoton to whom is that comment addressed, and what kind of point are you trying to make by it? Note that a block of red hot steel is also approximately a blackbody radiator, but will also reflect light.

Comment: It might be testable for two stars of completely different composition and emission temperatures (e.g., a pure hydrogen/young star and a heavy metal/old star) by looking at absorption and emission line differences.  I think this is still a stretch though as it would be difficult to distinguish the source of light in each case.  In the heavy metal star, the heavy ions will be partially ionized and will have corresponding absorption and emission lines...

Comment: If one had a "nice" scenario where the spectrum from the heavy metal star did not overlap well with some of these absorption lines but we clearly observed them, one might be able to infer that they result from the light from the second star.  I am not sure whether we can then take it a step further to determine reflectivity though.

Answer (score 3):

Stars are almost perfect black bodies so their emissivity is approximately one. As a consequence their absorbance is also approximately one and their reflectivity is approximately zero.

In the situation you describe the cooler star would absorb the light from the hot star and heat up. The increase in temperature would change its spectrum in accordance with Planck's law. If the cooler star rotated slowly enough, and the heat flow within it was slow enough, then the side nearer the hotter star could become detectably hotter and therefore different in colour. I would guess this is only likely in close binaries that are tidally locked.

A disclaimer: presumably if we cool the star enough for the optical surface to be mostly neutral gas rather than plasma the reflectivity could become significant and the argument above no longer applies. Whether such an object still counts as a star is debatable.

Comment: The surface of a star *is* mostly neutral gas - see https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/7883/what-is-the-degree-of-ionization-is-the-solar-photosphere for example. For many purposes Jupiter is also approximately a black body, but it very much does reflect light in the visible spectrum. I'm not saying this is wrong necessarily, but I don't think it's obvious, and I would need a citation to be convinced.

Comment: @Nathaniel I think you have misinterpreted that question and answer. The optical surface of star is the radius in the photosphere at with the degree of ionisation is great enough that it absorbs light. For a star like the Sun the optical surface is definitely ionised gas.

Comment: Ok, I'll take that, but given that there evidently *is* more neutral gas outside of that, it isn't clear to me that some incident light wouldn't be reflected from that gas, before it reaches the optical surface (so defined).

Comment: Sorry, neutral gas. Typo.

Comment: Jupiter is not transparent. It depends how much there is.

Comment: The optical surface of Jupiter is clouds i.e. droplets of condensed vapour. These don't exist in the photosphere of a star since it contains little but hydrogen and helium. Neutral hydrogen and helium are optically transparent in gaseous form.

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense. (But doesn't it affect your disclaimer?)

Comment: @Nathaniel I don't know enough about brown dwarves to know whether they might have neutral material that scatters light in their photospheres. And I guess neutron stars would have different light scattering properties. My disclaimer is that I can only comment on objects that fit the common description of a *star*.